# Calculating length and area with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, software-recommendations, google-maps-api

Google Maps API v2 had great methods for lines and polygons to calculate length and area.

v3 is lacking these methods (maybe just for now?).

What other options do I have for calculating line length and polygon area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daft Logic just updated to v3

http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-distance-calculator.htm

old v2 version
http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm

But for both line and area using v3 Google Maps API here:

http://demos.geojason.info/line-length-polygon-area-google-maps-v3-demo.php

Answer (score 2):

Will Cadell ([@geo_will](http://twitter.com/geo_will)) provided [an answer](http://twitter.com/geo_will/status/19311846477) for me on Twitter!  Check out the GPL [extendedApi for Google Maps v3](http://www.basicslabs.com/Projects/extendedApi/) package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Measure Tool library for Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

https://leafyjava.com/projects/measuretool

Really easy to use.

Here is a [live demo](https://leafyjava.com/projects/measuretool).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an Android app with many different measure features (area, distance, and angles measurements on Google Maps with different units): [Planimeter - GPS area measure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vistechprojects.planimeter)